# How to throuhly join two datatables using linq without column names

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

This is propably answered somewhere else, but I haven't found working solution yet.

I have two datatables and I want to join them into one datatable containing all data from both of them, or at least from the first of them and some columns from the second datatable.

I don't want to list all columns (totally 180) from the first datatable. I have tried eg. this

```
var JoinedResult = from t1 in table1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                   join t2 in table2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() 
                      on Convert.ToInt32(t1.Field<string>("ProductID")) equals t2.Field<int>("FuelId")
                    select t1;
```

but that gives only the columns from table1. How to get colums from table2 too to my result? Finally, I need to add my result to a dataset.

```
ResultSet.Tables.Add(JoinedResult.CopyToDataTable());
```

EDIT:

I ended up with this as the solution.
This follows an example given here [Create join with Select All (select *) in linq to datasets](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65021769-5e46-4256-9fdd-fda52293874f/create-join-with-select-all-select-in-linq-to-datasets?forum=csharpgeneral)

```
 DataTable dtProduct = dsProduct.Tables[0];
 DataTable dtMoistureLimits = ds.Tables[0];

 //clone dt1, copies all the columns to newTable 
 DataTable dtProductWithMoistureLimits = dtProduct.Clone();

 //copies all the columns from dt2 to newTable 
foreach (DataColumn c in dtMoistureLimits.Columns)
   dtProductWithMoistureLimits.Columns.Add(c.ColumnName, c.DataType);

   var ProductsJoinedWithMoistureLimits = dtProduct.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
       .Join(dtMoistureLimits.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(),// join table1 and table2
       t1 => new { ProductID = t1.Field<int>("ProductID"), DelivererID = t1.Field<int>("DelivererID") },
       t2 => new { ProductID = t2.Field<int>("MoistureLimits_ProductID"), DelivererID = t2.Field<int>("MoistureLimits_DelivererID") },
       (t1, t2) =>     // when they match 
       {    // make a new object
            // containing the matching t1 and t2
           DataRow row = dtProductWithMoistureLimits.NewRow();
           row.ItemArray = t1.ItemArray.Concat(t2.ItemArray).ToArray();
           dtProductWithMoistureLimits.Rows.Add(row);
           return row;
       });
```

However, in *dtMoistureLimits* there is not rows for all *"ProductID"* and *"DelivererID"* in *dtProduct*. Currently my solution returns only matching rows.

How to improve solution to return also those rows where there is not data for *"ProductID"* and *"DelivererID"* in *dtMoistureLimits*?

Comment: If you don't know the column names, how do you expect to do any future computation against them?

Comment: @NetMage, the resulting dataset is passed to a reporting environment. The column names are included in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using method syntax, without having to mention all columns

```
var result = table1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
   .Join(table2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>(),                      // join table1 and table2
      t1 => Convert.ToInt32(t1.Field<string>("ProductID")) // from every t1 get the productId
      t2 => t2.Field<int>("FuelId")                        // from every t2 get the fuelId,
      (t1, t2) => new                                  // when they match 
      {                                                // make a new object
           T1 = t1,                                    // containing the matching t1 and t2
           T2 = t2,
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, @Harald. Your answer lead me to the right path. After your solution I found an example from another forum, which I used in my code. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65021769-5e46-4256-9fdd-fda52293874f/create-join-with-select-all-select-in-linq-to-datasets?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0):

```
    var JoinedResult = (from t1 in table1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
               join t2 in table2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() 
               on Convert.ToInt32(t1.Field<string>("ProductID")) equals t2.Field<int>("FuelId")
               select new { T1 = t1,
                            T2 = t2.column_name // all columns needed can be listed here
                          }).ToList();
```

EDIT:
To convert the above result to a DataTable, use the following method:

```
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    //Get all the properties
    PropertyInfo[] Props = JoinedResult.Select(y=>y.T1).First().GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
    {
        //Defining type of data column gives proper data table 
        var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
        //Setting column names as Property names
        dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
    }

    dataTable.Columns.Add(t2_column_name, t2_column_type);

    foreach (var item in JoinedResult)
    {
       var values = new object[Props.Length];
       for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
       {
            //inserting property values to datatable rows
            values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item.T1, null);
       }
       values[Props.Length] = item.T2;
       dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
   }
```

Comment: This returns all required data but I don't know how to convert the result set into a datatable/dataset. The resulting data has the following data structure for one row:
{ t1 = {System.Data.DataRow}, column_name = 17.0000 }.
So, a single row of JoinedResult contains a DataRow element and a scalar value. How to convert that to a datatable in an elegant way?

Comment: Don't select `t1` as a whole, list down all it's columns too like `t1.column` etc. In that way you'll get the desired result

Comment: Ajay, listing all columns (180 columns all together) from table1 is not what I want to do.

Comment: @MarkkuRintala Listed a method to do that.

Comment: I need your solution in another case, but in your example for converting linq query result into datatable I get an error "A column named 'Item' already belongs to this DataTable" at `dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);`
The `Props[]`has values
`{System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[11]}
{System.String RowError}
{System.Data.DataRowState RowState}
{System.Data.DataTable Table}
{System.Object Item [Int32]}
{System.Object Item [System.String]}  
...
...
{System.Object Item [System.Data.DataColumn, System.Data.DataRowVersion]}
{System.Object[] ItemArray}
{Boolean HasErrors}